# App not rendering on browser after running services and pods

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

Problem Facing: When I try to run **kubectl apply** command on both the files below and try to see the app in the browser in http://192.168.49.2:30080/ the app did not render.I tried to run  minikube service fleetman - webapp --url but still no progress . Please Help !!!

**Additional information** :minikube ip -192.168.49.2 .

**Note**:I have installed docker Desktop app on my mac book air catalina.

**Browser message:** This site can’t be reached 192.168.49.2 took too long to respond.

**Docker image Link** :https://hub.docker.com/r/richardchesterwood/k8s-fleetman-webapp-angular

**first-pod.yaml file**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: webapp
 labels : 
   mylabelname: webapp
spec:
 containers:
   - name: webapp
     image: richardchesterwood/k8s-fleetman-webapp-angular:release0
```

**webapp-services.yaml file**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fleetman-webapp

spec:
  # This defines which pods are going to be represented by this Service
  # The service becomes a network endpoint for either other services
  # or maybe external users to connect to (eg browser)
  selector:
     mylabelname: webapp

  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30080

  type: NodePort
```

Comment: Isuue got resolved when I tried the command :kubectl port-forward web app 30080:80  and then ran the app on url http://localhost:30080/ , but I dont know why it was faling before .....

Comment: I was facing the same problem, the only difference is I am using minikube on Windows 10. This port forwarding solution works for me, while the accepted answer does not because --driver=none is not supported for minikube on Windows. Back to the cause of the problem, will it be because the firewall blocked the port 30080 on the minikube ip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating minikube with driver [none](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/none/):

```bash
$ minikube start --driver=none
```

> The `none` driver allows advanced minikube users to skip VM creation, allowing minikube to be run on a user-supplied VM.

Hence you will be able to communicate to your app via your host (ie. user-supplied VM) network address.